# validate required field depend on other field in model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I want create model that will validate required field in model that depend on other field condition.

```
public class FixedDeposit
{
   public int DebitAmount { get; set; }
   public string PAN { get; set; }
}
```

Now if the DebitAmount is greater than 50,000 then PAN field is must be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use MVC Foolproof validation package. This package provides you with many conditional validations in the form of annotations.

Complete list is here: 
http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

You can add this library to your VS project as a package:

[image: Package]
And, for your FixedPayment class, it should look something like this:

```
using Foolproof;
public class FixedDeposit
{
    public int DebitAmount { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("DebitAmount", Operator.GreaterThan, 50000)]
    public string PAN { get; set; }
}
```

**Alternate code**

```
using Foolproof;
public class FixedDeposit
{
    public int DebitAmount { get; set; }

    private bool _panRequired { get { return DebitAmount > 50000; } }
    [RequiredIf("_panRequired", true, ErrorMessage="PAN is required if Debit Amount is greater than 50000")]
    public string PAN { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had installed MVC Foolproof validation package. and use the syntax same as mention by you but all other validation are working except this one.

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternate implementation. I'm using something almost exactly the same as this alternative in my own app.

Comment: Working fine . Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement IValidatableObject

```
public class FixedDeposit : IValidatableObject
{
   public int DebitAmount { get; set; }
   public string PAN { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext   validationContext)
   {
      if (DebitAmount > 50000 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(PAN))
      {
        yield return new ValidationResult("PAN required for debits > 50,000.", new [] { "PAN" } );
      }
   }
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: This is the correct answer without adding extra packages to your application

Answer (score 2):

There are two options which you can use.

The first is the very easy to use and quite concise `ExpressiveAnnotations` JS library developed by Jaroslaw Waliszko. Follow this link to https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations for more information. This library allows you to perform different conditional validations.
Similarly to [Foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) it is added to your Visual Studio environment through adding the NuGet package. Once added, within your model add the using statement `using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes;` Then simply use the `RequiredIf` declaration to do what you need. For example:

```
public class FixedDeposit
{
   public int DebitAmount { get; set; }

   [RequiredIf("DebitAmount >= 50000")]
   public string PAN { get; set; }
}
```

The second option is to use `ModelState.AddModelError()`. This is done within your controller. Simply create a new method:

```
private void ValidateRequiredFields(modelname)
{
    if(modelname.DebitAmount >= 50000)
    {
        if(modelname.PAN == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("PAN", "Place whatever error message you want here");
        }
    }
}
```

Next you place a reference to your validation method in whichever view method you want this to be called. The line to reference is `ValidateRequiredFields(ModelName);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
        if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
        {
            ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, context);
            return result;
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    [RequiredIf("DebitAmount",50000, ErrorMessage = "PAN field is required")]
    public string PAN
    {get;set;
    }
```